# Google Chrome keyboard shortcut - close download bar

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome Auto-Close Download Bar](https://superuser.com/questions/111675/Google-chrome-auto-close-download-bar)

Is there any keyboard shortcut can close the file download bar, which is showing on the bottom every time when downloading files.

Comment: Most likely not, but there might be an AutoHotkey script!

Comment: I checked and it's not on the list, so you best change your question so someone will give you an actual solution ;-) BTW: this "might" be a duplicate from: http://superuser.com/questions/111675/google-chrome-auto-close-download-bar