# Keyboard friendly download manager for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, download-manager, chromium

I've been trying to use chrome lately, but just I can't get over the lack of keyboard navigation support. I've managed to improve in-page navigation with the use of extensions, but I'm still very much annoyed at chrome's standard download manager.

So, are there alternative download managers for Google Chrome? I'm mostly looking for something that allows me to open finished downloads with the keyboard, but general keyboard shortcuts support would be nice as well.

Edit: To be a little more specific, there are two major things that can't be done with the keyboard that annoy me the most. Closing that status bar, and saying "yes" when chrome asks me "Are you sure you want to download FILE?" every single time. I'm not asking if there's a way to close the status bar ([that's a covered topic](https://superuser.com/questions/111675/google-chrome-auto-close-download-bar)), I'm just asking for a different download manager altogether, I don't even care if it has a status bar.

(Technically I'm using chromium, but I don't think it matters.)

Comment: I newer versions of Chromium (Somewhere around 15.8x, I think), Chromium introduced a new Download Manager UI. For me, it has not changed the download UI one bit, but has led to zero notifications. It  downloads everything without asking for me. You can try enabling it in `about:flags`, and see if it helps.