# Keyboard shortcut for hiding downloads bar in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I download a file a bar appears at the bottom of the screen. Is there a keyboard shortcut for hiding it?

EDIT:
This was marked as duplicate but I still can't find the answer..

Comment: I hate when someone marks a question as "duplicate," but doesn't send the question asker in the right direction... This thread will address your question - http://superuser.com/questions/111675/google-chrome-auto-close-download-bar/484329

Comment: Why this is duplicate? I couldn't find the answer..
Can someone specify the actual keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @eyalev Certainly looks like a duplicate to me. Have you read the answers that refer to using keyboard shortcuts? Perhaps your question needs rewording?

Comment: @Tog This one: http://superuser.com/a/287463/205010 ? It requires two keyboard shortcuts while I'm looking for one keyboard shortcut.

Comment: This question is a duplicate because the question has been asked previously, multiple times, actually. That being said, I believe when a mod marks a question as duplicate, they should give the asker direction to the question that has already been asked. When the question already exists but does not have an answer, you have the ability to start a bounty on that question, essentially asking the same question again, but paying for an answer with your reputation points.

Comment: @TravisPflanz I still can't understand how this is a duplicate. I'm talking about a keyboard shortcut and http://superuser.com/questions/111675/google-chrome-auto-close-download-bar talks about auto hiding..

Comment: Do another search... I was just giving you ONE example of a SIMILAR question. I did not mark your question as duplicate. If you noticed, I said I hate when someone marks a question duplicate, but does not direct the asker to the "correct" place. The short answer - There is no keyboard shortcut, but there are extensions that will do the job... All of that is described in the answers in that thread.

Comment: Best answer in the other threads: open Downloads page, then close tab. On Mac, I push Cmd + Shift + J then Cmd + W.